How useful will the skills of analog circuit design be for researching in non-conventional computing?
I have interest in analog circuit design. I am planning to get into a job of analog circuit designing. However, my undergrad research topic lies in the field of non-conventional computing (neuromorphic computing to be specific). How relevant will the skills of analog circuit design be in the mentioned research field? If the skills are relevant, are they likely to keep being relevant in the near future?

Yes, those skills can be relevant. Analog design requires understanding of (besides electronics and semiconductors) systems and signals, physics, mathematics and more particularly aspects of accuracy, precision, noise and uncertainty.
These all apply to neuromorphic computing.
